# Create separate plane object from selected vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, vertices, faces

I would like to manually create some kind of hull of my 3D model.

I'm new to blender and I'm looking for a way to select the vertices of my shape and then generate a surface out of them.

I found the `F` shortcut online, but this edits the original shape.

I want to build a new shape from these vertices.

Eventually, the end goal is to merge all the little surfaces generated like this and create a wrap (like a hull).

Then I'll move on to my next challenge, which will be to give this wrap some real 3D textures (like the undulations of a plastic wrap around a fruit basket, for instance)

Comment: hello, could you please show your object? Is your hull a separate mesh? You could select the mesh, duplicate, then Alt S to fatten

Comment: You said 'manually'.. but just in case, you can Shift-D duplicate any part of your mesh, P separate to a new object, and use the Header > Mesh > Convex Hull operator on the dupe in Edit Mode.

Comment: Hi @RobinBetts , thanks for Shift-D and P, that's exactly what I was looking for. Feel free to post it as a proper answer :D As for the Convex Hull, In fact I don't want a convex shape. Right now I'll just do plane-by-plane, but I really wish I new how to make a 3D-surface out of these selected vertices.

Comment: @Myoch I guess the question would be.. which of the possible 3D surfaces? You mean the faces, as original, with holes filled, or something?

Comment: @Robin Betts, I think what I would expect would be that the algorithm detects the order in which I'm selecting the vertices, and then creates a triangulation step by step, using the last point, the previous one, and maybe either the second last or the closest in space (not entirely sure about that though). I want to wrap my shape by creating a non convex envelope, and I am starting doing it by creating planes from the Most outer regions. If there is a solution where I don't have to define it plane by plane, I'm happy to learn it.

Comment: @Myoch Hmm.. I think some kind of  illustration (especially of an awkward edge-case)  :) might help, here?